# Can a single molecule have a state?

Tags: thermodynamics, states-of-matter, nanoscience

I was studying a book about thermodynamics of nanosystems and I got stuck with this question in my mind which I couldn't find an answer for.

For instance, does a single water molecule have a state, like being liquid or something?
Or is one molecule of TiO2 solid or gas?
I would appreciate if anyone could clarify this.

I should state that I am not considering a macromolecule in my case.

Comment: Thermodynamics typically arises when there's a lot of something. For a fluid, you'll need a lot of constituent particles, molecules. However, a single molecule that is made up of a lot of atoms can have states; For example a single polymer (e.g. DNA) can be in a coiled state, or in a helix state.

Comment: @alarge:You should make an ans with some more details

Comment: also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal

Answer (score 2):

You can't build a liquid from a single molecule. Neither you build ice with a single molecule.

A single particle (in your case, molecule) has no state. A water molecule isolated from the rest of the water, "doesn't know" anymore that it belonged to a liquid state or a solid state, or to vapors.

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted!?

Comment: @HritikNarayan , I suppose you ask about answers. Then, of which one of the answers you ask?

Comment: The answer you posted is correct so I can't think of any reason why people have downvoted it.

Comment: @HritikNarayan  I can only thank you. Anyway, I enhanced the explanation a bit.

Comment: @HritikNarayan: Someone also flagged it as *low quality/not an answer*. I think it may be the shortness of the answer before the recent edit that prompted that, though it was a complete answer even before that.

Comment: Yep. True that.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : it's my fault. Sometimes, some additional, simple wording, is helpful. On the other hand without it, the answer doesn't convey clearly the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sofia. But let's say we release this isolated water molecule in a macrosystem consisting of L, G and S phases (that does not include water molecules). Wouldn't it be in a sense gas?

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, for proper phase transitions, and thus phases, to exist, you must in statistical mechanics take a thermodynamical limit, *i.e.* make the system infinitely large. In actuality this is a bit more involved (not to even start with nonextensive systems), but let's start working from this assumption.

1. Given that you need a lot of particles (mathematically, infinite) to define a phase, it is then clear that one particle does not a phase make. This is to say that a single molecule is not solid or gas.
2. That said, a single molecule that is made up of many atoms most certainly can have phases and phase transitions of its own: The molecule is a system of its own and if it has enough atoms, we can approximate as if it had an infinite amount. As an example, polymers can undergo the helix-coil transition.
3. Finally, consider the question of whether by looking at just a single molecule in a phase A, it is possible to identify the phase as A. Turns out that in practice it often is. In this sense a molecule does have a state identical to the macroscopic state. For example, the lipid bilayer has a gel-fluid phase transition. The gel is kind of a solid, where the molecules are packed in a rather ordered fashion, whereas in the fluid state the system is, in a sense, a 2D fluid. Now instead of looking at packing and symmetry at this scale, one could also measure the order parameters of the individual molecules: In the gel state the tails of the lipids are straight and in the fluid state they flap around more freely. This is to say that the molecules do have internal states that often correspond to the phase at the macroscale.

Comment: But this is a nonextensive system, isn't it?
And let me point out that I didn't mean a macromolecule ( I should have stated that)

Answer (score 0):

A single molecule doesn't have a state of matter. Single or individual molecules (when observed in Ion Traps) are considered to be "Gas". It requires a minimum of n(unknown to me) number of molecules to define the state of matter.

Comment: Single molecules have no state. You can't answer another question than what was asked. It wasn't specified in the question that the molecule is in an ion trap. I that case the molecule is in a structure, it is not single. A single particle has no state, whatever is the word you use for "defining" it, and whatever is the means by which you watch it. See what you wrote - It requires a minimum of n(unknown to me) number of molecules to define the state of matter.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

> The atoms in a solid are tightly bound to each other, either in a
> regular geometric lattice (crystalline solids, which include metals
> and ordinary ice) or irregularly (an amorphous solid such as common
> window glass).
>
> A liquid is made up of tiny vibrating particles of matter, such as
> atoms, held together by intermolecular bonds.
>
> Gas particles are widely separated from one another, and consequently
> have weaker intermolecular bonds than liquids or solids. These
> intermolecular forces result from electrostatic interactions between
> gas particles.

We see that a phase state is defined by the bonds between atoms/molecules rather than the particles themselves. (Although historically they were defined by more empirical properties, a solid retains its shape, etc.)

Comment: what if, then, a single molecule is in all the states of matter, since there is no violation to any of the above definitions?

Comment: How can a single molecule be held together by "intermolecular" forces?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth this is what I was referring to

Comment: If an item cannot physically possess a property, it surely cannot be a member of a set that requires that property.

Comment: if I tell you that the single molecule is tightly bound to all the other molecules, would you be able to provide a counterexample to disprove this?

Comment: Ah, my understanding (possibly mistakenly) of the question was that the atom/molecule was essentially *in vacuo*. The state of a particle derives from its interactions with neighbours, so I didn't think the question made sense in that context.

Comment: well I am considering a single molecule, far away from anything else, so that you can neglect any possible interaction with other matter

Answer (score 0):

A simple example for this question would be $\mathrm{H_2O}$

In liquid and gaseous states, the molecules are in random motion, whereas in solid state (ICE) these molecules form bonds with adjacent ones. A single molecule is the same in all the three states, what changes is the interaction between them.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a *state*?**
*State* or more precisely *state of matter* or *thermodynamic state* is a concept that is meaningful only when dealing with a thermodynamic system, i.e., a system consisting of many particles (where *many* usually means something of the order of the Avogadro number).

**What is a *molecule*?**
In many cases a molecule acts as a single particle - e.g., a molecule of $H_2$ in hydrogen gas or a molecule of $H_2O$ in water or water vapor or ice. However, a completely opposite situation is possible, where the molecule itself is a huge thermodynamic system with many constituing particles. Indeed, thermodynamic description is routinely applied to metals and semiconductor crystals, which aree ssentially single molecules. As an intermediate case one can think of macromolecules, such as polymers or organic molecules, which have as thermodynamical properties internal to them (e.g., one can use statistical physics to analyze the number of unzipped bonds in a DNA), as well as parts of a solution of many molecules (proteins in a cell), as well as the intermediate behavior, such as protein folding.